# moment js how to pass quarter number

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I am using moment.js. I am using the following code

```
moment().startOf('quarter').format('MM-DD-YYYY'), moment().endOf('quarter').format('MM-DD-YYYY')
```

It returns `April 1, 2018 - June 30, 2018`

It returns the current quarter date.

I want to get the start and end date of quarter 1,2,3,4.

In the above code how to pass the quarter number.

Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go.

Your current code is:

`moment().startOf('quarter')....`

Change this to:

`moment().quarter(3).startOf('quarter')...` // passed 3rd quarter here

Check the below working code:

```js
console.log(moment().quarter(3).startOf('quarter').format('MM-DD-YYYY'), moment().quarter(3).endOf('quarter').format('MM-DD-YYYY'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```

Check here for more information: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/quarter/